# How to implement Spring Security in integration test through JUnit in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

Here is the register method of AuthController shown below

```
public ResponseEntity<AuthResponse> register(@RequestBody RegisterRequest registerRequest) {

        var registeredUser = authService.register(registerRequest);

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(registeredUser.getUsername(), registerRequest.getPassword());
        Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authToken);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        String jwtToken = jwtTokenProvider.generateJwtToken(auth);

        AuthResponse authResponse = AuthResponse.builder()
                .accessToken(jwtToken)
                .message("success")
                .build();

        return new ResponseEntity<>(authResponse, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Here is the registerRequest method shown below

```
public RegisterRequest getRegisterRequest(){
        return RegisterRequest.builder()
                .username("testadmin")
                .password("testadmin")
                .countryCode("1")
                .lineNumber("1234567890")
                .firstName("First Name Admin")
                .lastName("Last Name Admin")
                .email("testadmin@afet.com")
                .organizationId(1L)
                .build();
    }
```

Here is the test class shown below

```
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class AuthControllerTest {

    private final String ADMIN_CONTROLLER_BASEURL = "/api/v1/admin";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private AuthService authService;

    @Mock
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Mock
    private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

    @Mock
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Mock
    private SecurityContext securityContext;

    @Test
    void shouldRegisterForAdmin() throws Exception {
   
        // Given
        RegisterRequest registerRequest = new UserBuilder().getRegisterRequest();

        User user = new UserBuilder()
                .withRegisterRequest(registerRequest,passwordEncoder).build();

        UserDTO userDto = UserDTO.builder()
                .username(user.getUsername())
                .firstName(user.getFirstName())
                .lastName(user.getLastName())
                .userRole(user.getUserRole())
                .countryCode(user.getCountryCode())
                .lineNumber(user.getLineNumber())
                .userStatus(user.getStatus())
                .email(user.getEmail())
                .lastLoginDate(user.getLastLoginDate())
                .build();


        AuthResponse authResponse = new AuthResponseBuilder()
                .withMessage("success")
                .withAccessToken("test_token")
                .build();


        // when
        when(authService.register(registerRequest)).thenReturn(userDto);

        when(authenticationManager.authenticate(any(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class)))
                .thenReturn(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDto.getUsername(),registerRequest.getPassword())); // ERROR LINE
        when(jwtTokenProvider.generateJwtToken(any(Authentication.class))).thenReturn("test_token");

        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

        // then - Perform the POST request and assert the response
        mockMvc.perform(post(ADMIN_CONTROLLER_BASEURL + "/register")
                        .contentType("application/json")
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(registerRequest)))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.accessToken").value(authResponse.getAccessToken()))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message").value(authResponse.getMessage()));

    }
```

I have got `404 User Name testadmin not found error`, I run the shouldRegisterForAdmin test method.

Error line is here shown below

```
when(authenticationManager.authenticate(any(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class)))
                .thenReturn(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDto.getUsername(),registerRequest.getPassword()));
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: while writing integration test cases u should use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock` annotation

Comment: @RyuzakiL How can I fix the issue if you have any idea about it?